# LibGDX Processing of clicking separate part of the Actor

Tags: java, android, libgdx

How to make so that not all actor reacted to clicking but only in it, i.e. I have only a small area the rectangular actor, and in it there is a square, on clicking on which there shall be an action?

Answer (score 0):

I assume there are different ways of doing that but one of the most straightforward one would be to create a button or another transparent image/actor and position it in the area of actor which you want to listen to click events. Then just add a clicklistener to this transparent image.